# Update a value in sharepoint list through workflow

Tags: infopath

I am a newbie to Infopath and Sharepoint.

My work till today.

I have created invoice template using infopath 2013. And Also created two views of the form. Submitter View and Print View.

I have a list(InvoiceNumberList) with temporary invoice number and final invoice number column.

When user clicks on submit it creates the temporary invoice number on the form and directed to the submitter view.Here, I am taking temp invoice number on the hidden field and making it as a column into the sharepoint library.

After that I am running workflow for the library in which the invoice template is published.

In workflow i have used following conditions.

If State= "Submitted"
     Update temporary invoice number(from the sharepoint column) into the InvoiceNumberList

Start approval process with current item.
     If workflow status is approved
           then I want to update final invoice number to the InvoiceNumberList.

I am not getting how to get value of final invoice number and update it into the list??
Please help me.

P.S Both final and temporary invoice number will be max(temp/final invoice number)+1

Answer (score 0):

In order to link the form to the SharePoint list you need to create a lookup column in the SharePoint that looks up into the ID of the form library. only then you will be to reference in the workflow.

Anyway, why do you want to create a separate approval process? when you can create the all approval process inside the form as demonstrated in the following demo by Laura rogers:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A78eLXRSh7g